# Kiel traduki ‘give a big hand’

Tags: translation, idiom

Kiel oni bone tradukus la anglan idiomaĵon ‘give a big hand’?

Mi pensis pri io kiel ‘bonvenige aplaŭdi’ sed verŝajne ekzistas traduko pli evidenta.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Mi certas ke mi estis en tia situacio kia en la angla ni dirus "give a hand" - sed mi ne memoras precize kion oni diris. Mi mem evitus laŭvortan tradukon kaj dirus (kun klariga mangesto) ion kia:

- Mi prezentas al vi Joĉjo Ikso
- Ni bonvenigu al Joĉjo Ikso
- Bonvolu laŭte aplaŭdi por ...
- Kunfrapu la manojn por ...
- Jam temp' está fari bruon por ...

Comment: Mi kontrolis en la Tekstaro por "applauxd" cxe "mano", "granda mano", "doni manon" k.s. kaj restas cxe la opinio ke oni evitu lauxvortajn tradukojn de nacilingvaj esprimoj en tiu okazo.

Answer (score 1):

Vi povas uzi plej abstraktan formon, forlasante la anologion. Sed laŭ PIV, vi ja povas uzi "mano" kiel analogion de "ilo uzita por…".

Do laŭvorte, vi povus traduki ĝin kiel "doni egan manon".

Franclingve oni diras "*prêter main forte*", do vi ankaŭ povus traduki tion kiel "pretigi fortan manon".

Do, kion ajn tradukon vi konstruas, uzi "mano" aŭ "helpo" estas ambaŭ taŭgaj. Rilate al la verbo kaj adjektivo, elektu ion ajn, kion vi preferas, dum via atentantaro komprenas vin, tiu estas bona.

Comment: La frazo "doni egan manon" sxajnas stranga al mi. Cetere la vorto "ega" en la senco "granda" estas evitinda. Laux PIV, ega estas: Plej forta, plej intensa, ekstrema: ega entuziasmo.

Comment: Mi konsentas, akorde al PIV, ŝajnas ke *lertega* tradukas *smartest* (plej lerta), kontraste al *smarter* (pli lerta), por kiu mi tiuokaze ne konas ekvivalentan afikson. Sed laŭ la [PMEG klarigoj](http://bertilow.com/pmeg/vortfarado/afiksoj/sufiksoj/eg.html), mi ne tute certas pri tio. Tutkaze oni povas elekti sian preferajn termojn el ["granda" enigo de la UEA tezaŭro](http://uea.org/vikio/SUGgranda).

Answer (score 1):

- Bonvolu aplaŭdegi por la viro.
- Aplaŭdegu por la viro.
- Ege aplaŭdu por la viro.