# Comparative and superlative in Esperanto

Tags: adjectives

As far as I know, one should use *pli* and *plej* for render comparative and superlative in Esperanto. So :

- longer : *pli longa*
- longest : *plej longa*

Now, following [this comment](https://esperanto.stackexchange.com/questions/2866/kiel-traduki-give-a-big-hand/2867#comment-2917), I wonder if -eg- can also be used to create superlative from the root.

I don't think so, to my mind *longega* means *tre longa* (very long), rather than longest ("most long"). But I would like to be more confident about that.

Also, if I'm wrong, then I would like to know if there is a comparative affix, even an non-official one, equivalent to the English suffix -er for short words. So longer ("more long") could also be translated *long▢▢a* beside *pli longa*.

Answer (score 10, accepted):

I explain it this way. The suffix *-eg-* is for making the next category of thing - bigger or more intense. So *domego* is not just a big house, but it's a mansion. *Kuregi* doesn't mean simply to run fast, but to sprint all out. Generally, if you're sprinting all out, you're moving at your personal **fastest**, but this doesn't mean that *kuregi* actually means "fastest".

I've never heard of an unofficial or even hypothetical comparative suffix. It's a big world though. Someone somewhere may have thought of one - but nobody payed it any attention.

Answer (score 2):

No. *Eg* is simply an amplifier.

> The suffix -eg- is the opposite of -et- and increases the size or
>   strength of the root http://pages.ucsd.edu/~dkjordan/eo/colloq/colloq130.html

- domo = house
- domego = mansion (this doesn't mean that it is the biggest mansion)

---

Mia dom**eg**o estas **pli** granda ol domo, sed ĝi ne estas la **plej** granda domego.

My mansion is bigger than a house (all houses), but it is not the biggest mansion.

Answer (score -1):

As a side note, *Plena Analiza Gramatiko* have the following remarks on superlative:

> Rim. Estas gene, ke la adverbo de tiu malsupereca komparativo estas kunmetita:
>   la akcento falas sur la prefikso mal, kaj la renkontigo kun sarnprefiksa adjektivo
>   estas fojfoje konfuzodona: ma/pli malfermita, mi petas! (kaj se la substantivo sa-
>   me komencigas: ma/pli maldolca malfelico ... ! ). Kurioze, la internacia formo kase
>   trovigas en la Fundamenta almenaii (al-men·au)

And PMEG also have a few words [about *men*](http://bertilow.com/pmeg/gramatiko/neoficialaj_vortetoj.html#i-m3k).

Also in the PAG and:

> Aca, ega kaj eta estas t.n. diafanaj suflksoj: ili ne sangas la gramatikan
>   karakteron kaj sencon de la radiko, nur modifas iom la lastan. En iliaj
>   derivajoj ili estas analizeblaj adjektive (ce substantivoj), aii adverbe
>   (ce adjektivoj kaj verboj): dometo: eta domo; grandega: ege granda;
>   parolaCi: aee paroli.

While [Volapuk seems to use *-um-*](http://mi.anihost.ru/Volapuk/Esperant/robert.htm), no affix seems to express the same meaning in Esperanto (which is fine to my mind, as it avoids language "orthogonality"). However one might also use the preposition as a prefix, according to PIV.